# What causes HP dv9700 laptop to turn off 1 second after turning on?

Tags: boot, laptop, hp-pavilion

model: dv9925nr

I removed the battery, plugged in a new AC adapter (light glows solid around DC jack). When I press the power button it powers on, the fan spins up, then there is a quiet click sound from inside (near the DC jack area) and it immediately shuts down. I have removed the HDD, CD-ROM, and tried each memory chip by itself. So, I would think it is a problem with the DC jack, fan, motherboard, CPU, or video. Any ideas?

Comment: did it work before?  what was the reason for the adapter?

Comment: I had this problem and it worked when I replaced the power adapter.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if it is not plugged in but running on battery alone?

Comment: The new adapter was just something my friend tried. And yes, the behavior is the same when starting off the battery alone.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an audible click, then you can be sure that there is a hardware issue. Since you've removed the HD and DVD, this leaves really only the fans or some mains power connector.

I'm afraid that this needs the tender loving care of a trusted engineer. :(